# Consume WCF service from IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-mobile

I created a `WCF Service Library` in `VS2012` and loaded it to my local `IIS`.
My client is a `Windows-Mobile 6.5` device and the configuration files for the client were generated using the `netcfsvcutil.exe`. during debugging everything worked great but when I uploaded the service to an external `IIS` i keep getting a `There was no endpoint listening...` exception even though the `netcfsvcutil.exe` generated the files from the external URL. this is the `web.config` file located on the remote server:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TestBinding" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MyService.CollectionService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService.ICollectionService" bindingConfiguration="TestBinding">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/CollectionService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and the client endpoint is generated like this:

```
public static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress EndpointAddress = 
    new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://1.2.3.4/MyService/MyService.CollectionService.svc");
```

I haven't made any configuration changes when i uploaded the service to the external `IIS`, i simply copied & pasted the files from one virtual directory to another.
some thing the might help is that the exception is raised without any timeout.

Answer (score 1):

The base address path and port do not match the endpoint address in your client configuration.

Address in your config: `http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/CollectionService/"`

Address in your endpoint:

```
http://1.2.3.4/MyService/MyService.CollectionService.svc
```

You need to change your endpoint code to

```
public static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress EndpointAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://1.2.3.4:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/CollectionService");
```